# how to throw an exception on a retrofit call

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, retrofit

I am making an api call using retrofit and I want to write a unit test to check if it returns an exception.

I want to force the retrofit call to return an exception

DataRepository

```
class DataRepository @Inject constructor(
        private val apiServiceInterface: ApiServiceInterface
) {

    suspend fun getCreditReport(): CreditReportResponse {
        try {
            val creditReport = apiServiceInterface.getDataFromApi() // THIS SHOULD RETURN AN EXCEPTION AND I WANT TO CATCH THAT
            return CreditReportResponse(creditReport, CreditReportResponse.Status.SUCCESS)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return CreditReportResponse(null, CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE)
        }
    }
}
```

ApiServiceInterface

```
interface ApiServiceInterface {

    @GET("endpoint.json")
    suspend fun getDataFromApi(): CreditReport
}
```

I have written a test case for getCreditReport which should validate the failure scenario

```
  @Test
    fun getCreditReportThrowException() {
        runBlocking {
            val response = dataRepository.getCreditReport()
            verify(apiServiceInterface, times(1)).getDataFromApi()
            Assert.assertEquals(CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE, response.status)
        }
    }
```

so to make the above test case pass, I need to force the network call to throw and exception

please suggest

Thanks
R

Comment: You can do this by giving wrong route in the GET method but there is a better way to test repository by creating Repository an Interface and then whenever you want to test Repository you can pass FakeRepository Implementation and it will make testing easier.

Comment: Could you share an example please

Answer (score 0):

Actually @Vaibhav Goyal provided a good suggestion to make your testing as easier. Assuming you are using MVVM structure, in your test cases you can inject a "mock" service class to mock the behaviours that you defined in the test cases, so the graph will be like this

[image]

Since I am using mockk library at the moment, the actual implementation in your code base would be a little bit different.

```
@Test
fun test_exception() {
    // given
    val mockService = mockk<ApiServiceInterface>()
    val repository = DataRepository(mockService)
    every { mockService.getDataFromApi() } throws Exception("Error")

    // when
    val response = runBlocking {
        repository.getCreditReport()
    }

    // then
    verify(exactly = 1) { mockService.getDataFromApi }
    assertEquals(CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE,response.status)
}
```

But if you want to test the exception thrown from Retrofit, then you might need mockServer library from square to help you to achieve this https://github.com/square/okhttp#mockwebserver

And the graph for this would be like this

[image]

You also have to setup the mock server to do so

```
@Test
fun test_exception_from_retrofit() {
    // can put in the setup method / in junit4 rule or junit5 class 
    val  mockWebServer = MockWebServer()
    mockWebServer.start()
    
    // given
    val service = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/").toString())
        .build()
        .create(ApiServiceInterface::class)
    val repository = DataRepository(service)

    // when
    mockWebServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
        .setResponseCode(500)
        .setBody("""{"name":"Tony}""") // you can read the json file content and then put it here
    )
    val response = runBlocking {
        repository.getCreditReport()
    }

    // then
    verify(exactly = 1) { mockService.getDataFromApi }
    assertEquals(CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE,response.status)
    
    // can put in tearDown / in junit4 rule or juni5 class
    mockWebServer.shutdown()
}
```

SO you can test different exception like json format invalid, 500 status code,data parsing exception

**Bonus point**

Usually I would put the testing json under test directory and make it almost same as the api path for better maintainence

[image]