# retrofit in kotlin coroutines Test case

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin, retrofit2

Im trying to write unit test for this class and as there is no enqueue for retrofit here I can not use execute in the unit test and at the same time i need to use run blocking for Coroutines. I'm confused, could you help me write a simple test with mock for this class?

```
class PriceService {
    private var apiInterface: APIInterface? = null

fun main(priceCallback: PriceServiceCallBack) {
    val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        println("Caught $throwable")
    }
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO ).launch(exceptionHandler) {
        apiInterface = APIClient.getClient()?.create(APIInterface::class.java)
        val response =  apiInterface?.prices()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            if (response!!.isSuccessful) {
                priceCallback.getData(response.body())
          } else {
                onError("Error : ${response.message()} ")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I guess you first you need to make your service injectable from outside so that you can easier to write the test case. Secondly, you have to expose your coroutine dispatcher , dun use the hard code one in here. And for the test case sample, I just post an answer in another question, could it help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68855764/how-to-throw-an-exception-on-a-retrofit-call/68924190#68924190

Comment: First of all, you should never call to API service from the UI or your VM. So, try to refactor your code and move this API call to a Repository layer and inject this repository in your VM. Doing that, it will be more easy to mock your tests and assert the results.